# Errors on core framework types after changing target framework to .Net Framework 4.0.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

When working with an existing project that has been changed from .Net Framework 4.0 to .Net Framework 4.0.1 (formally, **Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Platform Update 1 - Runtime Update (KB2478063)** ) in Visual Studio using the project properties, core types (i.e. `int` and `string`) become undefined. What's broken and how do you fix it?

Comment: Hopefully saving someone else from burning as much time doing the research when they run into this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the project references, the reference to mscorlib appears to be deleted as part of the update mechanism which changes the target framework version. Adding a new
   `<Reference Include="System.Core">4.0.1` entry to the project file cures the issue. This appears to need to be done in a text editor, as the built-in tooling doesn't provide an obvious control to force the reference back in.